# XDSOFT plugin datimepicker Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I'm using XDSOFT datetimepicker plugin, which I found here: http://easycodestuff.blogspot.in/2016/01/using-date-time-pickers-in-angularjs.html (very useful and informative blog) and I have set minTime, minDate to 0 which mean that only current date, time can be selected. That is fine for today and we will be allowed to set future time from now. But this is setting minTime to 0 even for future dates and making to select current time even for future date.

Here is a demo `plunker`: http://plnkr.co/edit/VThUaRaXAK3Ov4nAa5TZ?p=preview. Here  we can select today's date and current time but if I select tomorrow's date I'm allowed to select current time even for tomorrow.

I need a solution where any time can be selected for future date.

Also when a date is selected, the manually entry is still enabled,which means though minDate is set to 0, we can select any past dates. How to disable it once selected?

Will be thankful if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a function("onChangeDateTime") to check the date and set the time validation.

Try This Code, Working [Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/VfBW1hzoMHr4RDVJovQs?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.datetimepicker.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>DateTimePicker</h3>
        <input type="text" id="datetimepicker" onkeypress="return false" onpaste="return false"/>
        <br /><br />

        <script>   

            var d = new Date();
            var logic = function( currentDateTime ){
                if(d.getFullYear() + '-' + d.getMonth() + '-' + d.getDate() == currentDateTime.getFullYear() + '-' + currentDateTime.getMonth() + '-' + currentDateTime.getDate() ){
                    this.setOptions({
                        minTime:0
                    });
                }else{
                  this.setOptions({
                        minTime:'0:00'
                  });
                }
            };

            $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                minDate: 0,
                onChangeDateTime:logic,
                onShow:logic
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Time part is fine but is it possible to make the manual entry disable? lyk when the user enters a date and time, the input has to be disabled (r else user can still enter past date)and also how can I get it using angular directives. Here is a plunk of how i tried:http://plnkr.co/edit/iDnfY2QF2lpFQdpvLKAB?p=preview

Comment: for that you can make this text field readonly, but then picker is not working...

Comment: so try <input type="text" id="datetimepicker" onkeypress="return false" onpaste="return false"/>

Comment: Awesome.. that's what I need and how can I get it in angular way